# Subselect with not exists in insert into statement

Tags: sql, db2

The following works quite well:

```
SELECT ‘K’ CONCAT CHAR(PNR), FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
FROM S654321.PERSON P 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM S654321.CUSTOMER C 
                 WHERE C.FIRSTNAME = P.FIRSTNAME AND C.LASTNAME = P.LASTNAME)
```

I'd like to use this select as subselect in my insert:

```
INSERT INTO S654321.CUSTOMER
VALUES(SELECT ‘K’ CONCAT CHAR(PNR), FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
       FROM S654321.PERSON P 
       WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                        FROM S654321.CUSTOMER C 
                        WHERE C.FIRSTNAME = P.FIRSTNAME 
                              AND C.LASTNAME = P.LASTNAME))
```

But this statement isn't working.

CUSTOMER has the following structure:

- KNR (customer number) as varchar <-- primary key
- FIRSTNAME as varchar
- LASTNAME as varchar

Comment: Since you have not provided the structure of S654321.CUSTOMER, it is hard to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to use VALUES statement in this case. Try this

```
INSERT INTO S654321.CUSTOMER (KNR, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME)
SELECT ‘K’ CONCAT CHAR(PNR), FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
   FROM S654321.PERSON P 
   WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                    FROM S654321.CUSTOMER C 
                    WHERE C.FIRSTNAME = P.FIRSTNAME 
                          AND C.LASTNAME = P.LASTNAME)
```